# How to create a LFSR in c++ for different polynomials

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm trying to learn how `right >>` and `left <<` shift operations in c++. I've reading some articles in internet and some topics here, but I'm still confused.
I'm trying to code a *LFSR (Linear Feedback Shift Register)* based on users input who should give the *length, seed and polynomial tap position* as input to the LFSR code.

The code would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string seed;
    unsigned int length, pos;

    cout << "Type the length and the seed" << endl;
    cin >> length >> seed;
    cout << "Polynomial tap positions" << endl;
    cin >> pos;

    //Creating array with the LFSR size
    unsigned int *sizee = new unsigned int[length];
    //Convert the seed from char to int
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sizee[i] = seed[i] - '0';
    }
    //Shifting
    unsigned int seq = std::pow(2,length)-1;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= seq ; i++) {
        //Shift Operation here
        //Show user the value
    }

    delete[] sizee;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I shift bits, for example, the seed 00001 in a LFSR of length = 5 and Tap positions (Xor positions) 5 and 3 (x^5+x^3+1) to the right? I expect to obtain something like: 00001 > 10000 > 01000 > 00100 > 10010, and so on, until the end of the loop, considering Fibonacci as architecture type.

Comment: Can you elabortate for users who don't know what a LFSR is? Surely, your problem is more basic than LFSR.

Comment: `std::pow(2,length)` makes me sad

Comment: @Walter LFSRs are using to generate pseudo-random numbers "automatically", you can find more explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register. Harold, I don't get your point. Im new to c++, sorry.

Comment: @LeonardoAlves you're doing a bitshift using floating point exponentiation, on the "silly scale" that's just one step better than converting to a string in binary, appending zeroes, and then parsing it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to encode an LFSR in an integer on a computer, you need to first understand the representations used by LFSRs and integers.  There are two important issues/differences:

- LFSRs usually number their bits starting with 1, with a tap at bit
  *i* corresponding to having *x<sup>i</sup>* in the polynomial
- integers usually number their bits starting with 0, with bit *i* corresponding to a value of *2<sup>i</sup>*
- LFSRs are traditionally shown with bit 1 on the left, and the highest bit on the right
- integers are usually written in big-endian form, with bit 0 on the right and the highest bit on the left

Those lead to two important things when you use integers for LFSRs:

- bit *i* of the LFSR becomes bit *i-1* of the integer
- the right shift of the LFSR becomes a left shift of the integer.

so your basic LFSR step becomes:

```
seed = (seed << 1) | parity(seed & polynomial)
```

where `seed` is the contents of the LFSR (plus extra bits shifted out previously when your integer size is larger than your LFSR length), `polynomial` is the tap bits -- an integer with bit *i-1* set for each *x<sup>i</sup>* in the polynoimal, and `parity` is a function that computes the xor of all the bits in an integer -- can be done with flag tricks or a single instruction on most CPUs, but there's no easy way to express it in C.

Comment: I got it. But, what I really trying to understand is what `(seed << 1)` does. It moves the value 1 to left _seed_ times?

Comment: @LeonardoAlves: `(seed << 1)` shifts the value from `seed` 1 bit position to the left.  So bit 1 comes from bit 0 of seed, bit 2 from bit 1, etc.  A `0` is shifted in to bit 0.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you @Chris

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will not be able to use the >> and << operators as you have an array of ints.

The << and >> operators are only defined for numeric data types. You should switch to using just an int.

With a single int your algorithm for a LFSR becomes:

```
Calculate your tap bit: tapbit = necessary bits XORed ( ^ ) together
// ^ Note this will require shifts as well, I'd reccomend a for loop through all your taps

Shift register to the right: seed = seed >> 1;
Set the leftmost bit to the calculated tap bit: seed = seed | ( tapbit << length );
```

Comment: Thats what I have in mind. But, what would be the seed type? and how would I define "the positions" to XOR them?